# Difference between Maverick and eccentric

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was reading GRE vocabulary when i came across these two words. There dictionary definition is very similar to each other. They both stand for unconventional behaviour. Two examples :

> *He is a **maverick** who sometimes rebels against his own party.*
>
> *Most of the artists are **mavericks**.*

In the second sentence it looks eccentric can also go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions might seem similar, but they are not closely related in use at all.

"Maverick" connotes more of a willful rebellion, as in someone who actively chooses not to do things the same way as everyone else. A maverick tends to be someone strong-willed or principled in their nonconformity.

"Eccentric" is used more accurately to describe someone who is strange or odd, which may not necessarily be purposeful or understood by other people.

Comment: @geekahedron..I have understood maverick but facing difficulty in understanding the usage of eccentric. Can you please provide me examples of eccentric personality? A sentence or two would do for me.

Comment: It may help to take a look at the Wikipedia page on "eccentricity": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(behavior)

Comment: @geekahedron..thanks for the link. The main problem i have in understanding this word is that at some places it is used to describe a positive trait of a person. Sometimes to describe the negative trait. For some mad behaviour it is said that a person is eccentric. At some places eccentric is used to describe positive quality like genius or creative. That is same in the wikipedia link also.

Comment: @SudhirSharma Yup - eccentric in and of itself is neither positive nor negative, which is why you're having that confusion.

Comment: So its useless to say 'he is an eccentric person.' If the context is missing it would be useless.

Comment: @David Rice..Is this correct?

Comment: @SudhirSharma No - it would mean that he was eccentric. He does things oddly, or has some non-typical behaviors, but it doesn't say anything about whether he's good or bad.  Kind of like saying "she has red hair" or "he plays basketball".  They can be true statements, and informative statements, but not judgments.

Comment: @David Rice...Thank you very much.Very interesting word. Do you think weirdo is a good synonym for this word

Comment: @SudhirSharma It's close, but weirdo is generally considered an insult.  I'd more likely use the words "odd" or "peculiar" which don't have those kinds of negative connotations.

Comment: Just a note on usage; while "eccentric" can be used as a noun it's much more commonly seen as an adjective.

Comment: Do you mean that mavericks have their own morals and values, which are just not shared by the majority?